# MATLAB: Create area at z-axis

Tags: matlab, 3d, area

In MATLAB, the area-function can be used to created a shaded area from data. For example:
area([xmin xmax],[ymin ymax])
This are is drawn at the z-axis z= 0.
How can I make a shaded area plot at a certain z-distance (so basically just a slice)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the patch of fill3 functions:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/introduction-to-patch-objects.html

Simple example:

```
X = [0 1 1 0];
Y = [0 0 1 1];
Z = [0.5 0.5 0.5 .5];
fill3(X,Y,Z,'g')
```

in which you play with the z coordinate. Is that what you meant?